# How to get page URL in Web API controller?

Tags: url, asp.net-web-api

Site 1:  test.page.com/News

Site 2:  www.page.com/News

Site 3: m.site.com/News

Hi I 'm calling a pageapi.

Web Api url:http://www.pageapi.com/api/GetNews

How can I get website url(http://m.site.com/) in my Getnews api controller? Which page post my api?

I try  Url.Request, Request.RequestUri,HttpContext.Current.Request.Path . But I 'didn't get. Always get web api url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri
```