# HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer is Null in WebApi Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

[This doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368328/how-to-get-page-url-in-web-api-controller) I need to set CookieHeaderValue.Domain property in web API controller for the client, for that I need to get the URL of the client that made request to WebApi Controller. My WebApi Controller and Client are 2 separated projects that I made.

How to get URL of the client that made request in the WebApi Controller?

**P.S.** I have WebApi controller which allows client to make certain requests based on Digest, Basic and OAuth 2 using OWIN Authorization. I have a client that get user input, make async request to MVC controller with jQuery which internally calls WebApi controller, returns response data and return it as a partial view on the client side. I can't provide all the code. What code should I provide in this case to fit MCVE requirement ? Thanks.

My WebApi Controller:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetEmployeeById(int id)
    {
        var test = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer; // UrlReferrer is null
```

This is how request is sent:

```
private static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseCookies = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
};

private HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    ... // Create request info
    var response = client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: what do you mean by the url of the client? ip address of the machine you client is hosted to? if you use fiddler, or browser address string then there is no referrer by definition, therefore it is null

Comment: if you try to get referrer on HomeController you'll get it (it will be your site's http address). Then you are able to pass it as a header or part of body to your internal API.

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear but I think you may be looking for the [`Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.host?view=aspnetcore-7.0) property.